Stop chrome devtools logging mouse events temporarily
I'm trying to log a specific mouse event, which is being sent from an onMouseMove event. I'm absolutely positive that I've seen some sort of keyboard shortcut that you can use inside of chrome devtools to stop chrome from logging mouse events after one has been sent that you're interested in inspecting, but for the life of me I can't remember or find it in the docs anywhere. In my case, I'm trying to log event in the center of the object I'm targeting so I can see what certain values are at that location, but when I move the mouse out of the object that event is buried under dozens of other mouseMove events.
Thanks in advance!

Assuming it's a "logging breakpoint" the hotkey is Ctrl-F8 in devtools.

I believe you are looking for the debugger:
w3schools

The debugger statement stops JavaScript execution and calls the
debugger.

Just paste it into Devtools
setTimeout(function() {
   debugger;
}, 2000);

With this, the debugger will be activated after 2 seconds, giving you time to position the mouse where you want to check for events.
